# How to call custom functions within watch?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to call a function `isChanged` from `watch`:

```
 watch: {
    items: {
        handler: function(revised, original) {
            for (let i = 0; i < revised.length; i++) {
                if (isChanged(original, revised[i])) {
                    // update
                }
            }
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
      isChanged(original, item) {
          // code here to check if item is changed
      }
    }
  }
```

Wherever I put `isChanged`, it indicates:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "items": "ReferenceError: isChanged is not defined"
```

Where can I put `isChanged` so it can be seen? What if I wanted to use an imported function in another module?

Comment: `this.isChanged`

Comment: Just confirmed my method won't work because `revised` and `original` are objects and they reference the same thing so the tests will always indicate they are the same. Will post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this`, as the method is part of your component.

Like this :

```
watch: {
    items: {
        handler: function(revised, original) {
            for (let i = 0; i < revised.length; i++) {
                if (this.isChanged(original, revised[i])) {
                    // update
                }
            }
        }
    }
  },
```